# Access default variable on cfmodule attributes

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I am using cfmodule with a template and I'm hoping to access the default values of the module, even if other values are passed in. Is that possible in some way? Outputting the attributes scope just has the entire data passed in with no indication of the value.

Example.

`<cfmodule fielda="#data#" template="myTemplate.cfm" />`

myTemplate.cfm

`<cfparam name="attributes.data" default="1" />`

Assuming data has a value of 2. Is it possible from within myTemplate.cfm to know the default value was 1?

Comment: AFAIK, there's no way to pull a collection of `<cfparam>` defaults in any context.

Comment: Agreed. I think the best you could do is simulate it by duplicating the arguments structure (or just the key names) *before* any `cfparam name="arguments.."` statements are executed. Then dynamically compare it with the contents of `arguments` after the params.  Any keys the two structures have in common are the arguments that were explicitly passed into the module. Not a fantastic solution, but would probably achieve the goal..

Comment: @SOS I thought about this. We're trying to get a self-documenting solution. We were going to store defaults in the database with the components and load the defaults into the params. But then to see the documentation we have to go to the database. By keeping it in the code it's there when working, but then we can't reference it with some other stuff we're trying to do in our CMS. This was just one option which doesn't look like an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really possible. All that the template can do is include a bunch of HTML into your template.

But the solution is simple: Use a .cfc instead. Instead of `<cfmodule>`ing a template, call a function that outputs HTML. Unless it is sent a parameter "mode=diagnostic" or some such, in which case it doesn't output anything, but instead it returns a struct.

So you can call the function in diagnostic mode, read the struct, or call it in default mode and output stuff.

Makes sense?

Comment: Yeah. I have a complex problem I'm trying to solve with a custom CMS wherein I want to know which data a module uses. Example I have a large data object passed into the module. The module however uses a cfparam with a default value of default={prop1='',prop2=''}. (We mainly use that to document which props are needed from the obj.) The object passed in may have prop1 and prop2 but has other properties. I'd like to be able to determine with code that the module has prop1 and prop2 defined without another line of code to sort of cache/log that away. I was hoping I could access that piece.